Does there exist a relation between character size interline space
yesterday, a customer said: “if character size is 12 pt, You set interline x pt, if character size is 18, interline must be y pt…”like there is a corrispondence between character size and interline.
Is it so?
I mean: If I set Article class, 12 pt character or 18 pt, do the interline is always the same or it is different. I said: "it's different...". Is it true?
Thank you
Renato

Yes, the absolute value distance should be different and with LaTeX it also is by default.

I don't think this question is on topic. Anyway, the answer is a big no. Font size is just a label and there are “big” and “small” nominally 10pt fonts. Other factors can enter the scene; for instance, typesetting in German may require wider leading, because of the many uppercase letters and the umlauts.

why this question is not "on topic". The Topic of this forum is not LaTeX?

@RenatoP seems on topic to me, but I always like to disagree with egreg

The focus seems to be to the question if the interline space should differ for different font sizes. This would be a typography question and IMHO off-topic. Only the question about “Article class” seems to be on-topic (but article does not support 18pt as document font size, so it is also somehow strange). Maybe you should add example code of what you mean.

thank you to all.
my question it’s not about Tex, but LaTeX. I would know if LaTeX take care about the interline space related at the character type ansize. And you answered me: 20% more of the character size .automaticaly. That’s what I want to know

This is specified when the class sets up font sizes.
If you use
\fontsize{5pt}{5cm}\selectfont abc...

You get 5pt font set to lines that are 5cm apart. If you look in your document class it probably defines \tiny, ... \normalsize...\large  in similar ways, perhaps with better chosen values.

you mean that is not enough to set class name, i.e.:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}, I need to specify with \fontsize...
Is it?

@RenatoP  No I mean article class has made a choice. eg at [10pt] option it defines \DeclareRobustCommand\large{\@setfontsize\large\@xiipt{14}}  so \large is 12pt font on 14pt baseline, but other classes may have chosen different values. Nothing is built in to the font or to latex itself.

so, if I want a specific value, I need to specify it!

@RenatoP for example if you use [12pt] option then \normalsize is \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xiipt{14.5}  so the same 12pt font but set on a larger 14.5pt baseline, so even just looking at article class there is no direct relationship between font size and baseline spacing

@RenatoP you should not be using such explicit sizes within the document body, but you can use a modified class or redefine the sizes in teh document preamble

@RenatoP Some classes, e.g., the KOMA-Script classes, allow to define your own font size files. By default KOMA-Script classes use scrsize10pt.clo, scrsize11pt.clo and scrsize12pt.clo, but the prefix scrsize can be changed, so you can easily use changed versions of these files. You can also define new files, e.g., for 14pt or 14bp.
